After Spring Boot 3 update: Authentication token not saved in SecurityContext
In my application I have implemented custom otp authentication. It was working correctly with Spring Security 5 but after updating to boot3 and Spring Security 6 it stopped working. Authentication is working just fine but it seems that the authenticated object is not stored in context and subsequent requests responds with 401.
The security configuration looks like this:


    @Bean("otpSecurityFilterConfiguration")
        @Order(1)
        public SecurityFilterChain otpSecurityFilterChainConfiguration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
            OtpAuthenticationFilter otpAuthenticationFilter = new OtpAuthenticationFilter(createOtpAuthenticationManager(),
                    authenticationSuccessHandler, authenticationFailureHandler);
    
            http
                    .securityMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"))
                    .addFilterBefore(otpAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    .formLogin(form -> form.loginProcessingUrl("/login"))
                    .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .exceptionHandling(handler -> handler.authenticationEntryPoint(otpAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                            .requestMatchers("/auth/sendOtp").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED))
                    .headers(headers -> headers
                            .contentTypeOptions(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    
            return http.build();
        }
    
    private AuthenticationManager createOtpAuthenticationManager() {
            return new ProviderManager(otpAuthProvider);
        }


And the otpAuthenticationFilter which extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter captures the /login request, creates authenticated token and process further


    @Slf4j
    public class OtpAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    
    
        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            
            if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
            }
            
            String code = request.getParameter("code");
            String uid = request.getParameter("uid");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            
            log.info("Received authentication request with email: {} and uid: {}", email, uid);
            
            String sessionKey = OtpAuthUtils.getSessionKey(uid, email);
            
            OtpCode sessionCode = (OtpCode) request.getSession().getAttribute(sessionKey);
            validateOtpCode(sessionCode, code, sessionKey, request);
            log.info("Otp code validated successfully. User {} is now authenticated", email);
            
            OtpAuthenticationToken authRequest = new OtpAuthenticationToken(email, uid);
    
            setDetails(request, authRequest);
    
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
        }


Above code works just fine, token is authenticated, OtpProvider, which creates UserDetails from token is also called.
Now according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository in Spring Security 6 context must be saved in securityContextRepository. This is the change from Spring Security 5 that may explain my case but my otp filter which extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter should have this handled. Method AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#successfulAuthentication which creates authenticated SecurityContext and saves the context in securityContextRepository is called.


protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContext context = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(authResult);
    this.securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);
    this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);


Finally i managed to make this work disabling securityContext explicit save. But it seems this is not a valid solution.

.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false))

How to make this work without disabling explicit save?
Edit:
I do not set SecurityContext manually AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is setting it. I do not override onSuccessfullAuthentication method.
Provider code:


    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class OtpAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
          
            OtpAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = (OtpAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    
            if (OtpAuthUtils.isValid(authenticationToken)) {
                log.info("Commencing {} authentication using {} provider", authenticationToken.getEmail(), this.getClass().getName());
                LoggedUser user = new LoggedUser(authenticationToken.getEmail(), authenticationToken.getSignProcessUid());
    
                //setAuthentication(true) is forbidden, we need to create another object
                OtpAuthenticationToken authenticationResult = new OtpAuthenticationToken(user, user.getAuthorities());
                authenticationResult.setDetails(authenticationToken.getDetails());
    
                return authenticationResult;
            } else {
                throw new OtpCodeValidationException("Authentication token is not valid");
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class authentication) {
            return OtpAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
        }
    
    }


In short here is how it works in my application:

User receives uid via email. This uid can be used to to access /auth/sendOtp
/auth/sendOtp creates unauthenticated session and sends otp code to user mobile
User enters uid and otp code via /login then new authenticated session is created

Authentication logs:

DEBUG [FilterChainProxy:223] - Securing POST /login?email=user@gmail.com&uid=xxx&code=xxx
INFO [OtpAuthenticationFilter:50] - Received authentication request with email: user@gmail.com and uid: xxx 
INFO [OtpAuthenticationProvider:18] - Commencing user@gmail.com authentication using pl.gisit.otp.security.OtpAuthenticationProvider provider
INFO [OtpAuthenticationProvider:25] - Generated authentication token OtpAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoggedUser{signatoryId=null, signProcessUid=xxx, email=user@gmail.com, authorities=[]}, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=8FF0AC1F3CEE8AB3FFB0334286B0FFB0], Granted Authorities=[]]
DEBUG [OtpAuthenticationFilter:327] - Set SecurityContextHolder to OtpAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoggedUser{signatoryId=null, signProcessUid=xxx, email=user@gmail.com, authorities=[]}, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=8FF0AC1F3CEE8AB3FFB0334286B0FFB0], Granted Authorities=[]]


Actually the last log is called by AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#successfulAuthentication where securityContextRepository is being populated:

    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContext context = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
        context.setAuthentication(authResult);
        this.securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(context);
        this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);
        if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            this.logger.debug(LogMessage.format("Set SecurityContextHolder to %s", authResult));
        }

Now subsequent request logs:

20-06-2024 16:48:57 [::] DEBUG [FilterChainProxy:223] - Securing POST /auth/validateSession 
20-06-2024 16:48:57 [::] DEBUG [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:119] - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext 
20-06-2024 16:48:57 [::] DEBUG [HttpSessionRequestCache:80] - Saved request http://localhost:8080/otp/auth/validateSession?continue to session 
20-06-2024 16:48:57 [::] ERROR [OtpAuthenticationFailureEntryPoint:36] - Auth exception 
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAccessDeniedException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
20-06-2024 16:48:57 [::] WARN  [OtpAuthenticationFailureEntryPoint:37] - OTP authentication failure on /otp/auth/validateSession cause: Full authentication is required to access this resource

After disabling explicit save the subsequent request logs are:

20-06-2024 17:02:05 [::] DEBUG [FilterChainProxy:227] - Secured POST /auth/validateSession 
20-06-2024 17:02:05 [::] DEBUG [DispatcherServlet:120] - POST "/otp/auth/validateSession", parameters={} 
20-06-2024 17:02:05 [::] DEBUG [RequestMappingHandlerMapping:531] - Mapped to pl.gisit.otp.controller.SecurityController#main(ValidateSessionRequest) 
20-06-2024 17:02:05 [::] DEBUG [RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:120] - Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [ValidateSessionRequest(signProcessUid=3b1afa70-71b7-4bcc-8af7-aa63f3ed3cb6, email=user@gm (truncated)...] 
20-06-2024 17:02:05 [::] INFO  [SecurityController:33] - Security context holder auth OtpAuthenticationToken [Principal=LoggedUser{signatoryId=null, signProcessUid=3b1afa70-71b7-4bcc-8af7-aa63f3ed3cb6, email=user@gmail.com, authorities=[]}, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=8F4DB425A41AE000C6FC05B17D18717D], Granted Authorities=[]] 
20-06-2024 17:02:05 [::] INFO  [SecurityController:41] - Session correctly validated for uid 3b1afa70-71b7-4bcc-8af7-aa63f3ed3cb6 and user user@gmail.com  


why not read the docs the section named Security Context https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder

I read it and I don't see anything that explains my case. Do you mean I should manually set SecurityContext  instead of relying on spring?

what i can see (of the small amount of code you have provided) you have more custom code then you are actually showing otpAuthProvider points to that you have written some form of custom provider, which means that you are in fact, not relying on spring. The parameter that you needed to switch points to the fact that you are manually somewhere setting the SecurityContext without explicity saving it. By setting the flag you are reverting back to old. Its hard for us to help you unless you actually post all your custom code and full logs. Because i cant replicate anything from the code provided

@Toerktumlare thank for feedback. I think that I am relying on AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#successfulAuthentication to save SecurityContext. I do not set it anywhere in my code. See my updated my post.

It is hard to say anything definitive about these kind of things. What is true is that major API changes have been done to Spring Security (several times actually) because people were effectively always doing things wrong, modern Spring Security versions have unified a lot of things so there should be only one way to do it. There is a good chance that whatever is causing the issue here falls in the "it was always wrong" boat. When faced with something like that I stop looking for a solution to the problem, I try to find the Spring Boot 3 way to fullfill the requirement instead.
